# PHP echo inside a LABEL tag

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to echo inside Label tag? I am not able to print this at all? It shows blank?

```
 <label for="Name" class="styled">
 <font size="7" face="Arial Black" color="#A33F3A">Number of people in <?php echo $name;?>:</font></label>

 <p align="center">

 <p align="center">

 <p align="center">

 <label for="Mall Name" class="styled">
 <font size="6" face="Arial Black" color="#A33F3A"><?php echo $count;?></font></label>
```

Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: It certainly is. Are you sure $count has a value ? do var_dump($count);

Comment: I can bet you that     $count doesn't have a value.

Comment: OK atleast name should come up because I am using the $name in textbox it is coming up there...

Comment: @TheDevMan, From the code you've shown, there is no problem.  Also, make sure you use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary values you are using in an HTML context.

Comment: please note the font tag is depracated

Comment: Since I see only html here and you have php code inside `.html` file it might be ignored by php interpreter. So it will be sent as html document. This means that `<?php echo $count;?>` should be in _view source_. If this is the case you can configure server to interpret `.html` files as well.

Comment: warning: the `<font>` tag is deprecated.

Comment: `<p align="center">` is recommended to change to `<div style="margin: auto;">` too

Answer (score 1):

PHP has no concept of where it is when you perform an action. Echoing in a label is just as good as echoing anywhere else. Just make sure that anything that you accept from users either directly or indirectly goes the through htmlspecialchars unless it is intended to have markup in it.